# solving arduous limit

Tags: calculus, limits

How to simplify the following:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin (\pi / 2 - 10 \sqrt x) \ln ( \cos (2x))}{(2^x -1)((x+1)^5-(x-1)^5)}$$

Here is what I've done:

$$ \sin (\pi / 2 - 10 \sqrt x) = \cos 10 \sqrt x$$
$$(x+1)^5-(x-1)^5 = 10x^4 +20 x^2 +2$$

So:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {\cos (10 \sqrt x) \ln ( \cos (2x))}{(2^x -1)(10x^4 +20 x^2 +2)}$$

What else can be done? I've started to use L'Hopital's rule but it makes things worse, i.e. more terms and more. Probably, there is a way to make the fraction simpler?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Maclaurin series expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(\pi/2-10\sqrt{x})}{(x+1)^5-(x-1)^5}=\frac{\sin(\pi/2)}{1-(-1)}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
So, it remains to consider
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(\cos(2x))}{2^x-1}.
$$
Try applying L'Hopital's rule to this last limit. Then, combine your results.

Comment: So, in $\lim \frac {f\cdot g}{h \cdot k}$, where f,g,h,k are functions, I am allowed to calculate limits separately on condition that they are not equal zero?

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(\cos(2x))}{2^x-1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac {1}{\cos(2x)} \cdot (- \sin 2x) \cdot 2 / (2^x ln 2)  = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{ 1 \cdot 0 \cdot 2} {1 \cdot ln 2} = 0 $

Comment: As long as all relevant limits exist, you can break up over addition/subtraction/multiplication; as long as the denominator's limit is non-zero, you can also break up over division.  But here, we've only actually broken up in to three parts: the two in the first equation, and the third.